# Spark on HDInsights - No FileSystem for scheme: adl

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

I am writing an application that processes files from ADLS.  When attempting to read the files from the cluster by running the code within spark-shell it has no problem accessing the files.  However, when I attempt to sbt run the project on the cluster it gives me:

[error] java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: adl

```
implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("AppMain").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val listOfFiles = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("adl://adlAddressHere/FolderHere/")

val fileList = listOfFiles.collect()
```

This is spark 2.2 on HDI 3.6

Answer (score 2):

In your `build.sbt` add:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-azure-datalake" % "2.8.0" % Provided
```

I use Spark `2.3.1` instead of `2.2`. That version works well with `hadoop-azure-datalake 2.8.0`.

Then, configure your spark context:

```scala
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val hadoopConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.adl.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.adl.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.Adl")
hadoopConf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
hadoopConf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id", clientId)
hadoopConf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.credential", clientSecret)
hadoopConf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url", s"https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token")
```

---

#### TL;DR;

If you are using RDD through spark context you can tell Hadoop [Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.5/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) where to find the implementation of your [`org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/adl/AdlFileSystem.html).

The key come in the format `fs.<fs-prefix>.impl`, and the value is a full class name that implements the class [`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html).

In your case, you need `fs.adl.impl` which is implemented by [`org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/adl/AdlFileSystem.html).

```scala
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val hadoopConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.adl.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem")
```

I usually work with Spark SQL, so I need to configure spark session too:

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("fs.adl.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem")
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id", clientId)
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.credential", clientSecret)
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url", s"https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found if I package the jar and spark-submit it that it works fine so that will work for the mean time.  I'm still surprised it would not work in local[*] mode though.

Comment: Did you find the actual root cause though? Are you aware of any public packages that can used through spark-submit ?

Comment: I did not figure out why this was happening.  Sorry.